# MySQLi not displaying variables

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason my MySQLi query is not displaying any variables, and all code that's in between the while(){ function is not displaying.

Any help is appreciated

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `postedby`,`headline`,`article`,`date`,`image`,`imagecaption` FROM `blogentries` WHERE `ID` = ? LIMIT 1,1");
//Prepare, bind and execute statement
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute( ) or die ("Could not execute statement");
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($postedby, $headline, $article, $date, $image, $imagecaption);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
?>
```

Comment: where are you setting value for $id ?

Comment: Are you checking that the query runs successfully? How many rows is it returning?

Comment: The variable is right above $stmt prepare.